# Can't inspect values in java debugger VScode

Tags: java, debugging

I am remote debuggin a java application in VScode, and for some reason, I can't inspect the values of variables during debugging

[image]

As you can see, I am trying to watch the variable "serverMessages", but after the variable has been set I'm getting the error `Cannot evaluate because of compilation error(s): serverMessages cannot be resolved to a variable.`

My launch.json looks as follows:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "java",
            "name": "Attach to Remote Program",
            "request": "attach",
            "hostName": "localhost",
            "port": 51000
        },
    ]
}
```

I start the application with the following command

`java -jar ../server.jar -l ../levels/SAD1.lvl -c "java -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=localhost:51000,quiet=y searchclient.SearchClient -bfs" -g -s 150 -t 180`

I'm not sure which other information I should provide. Does anyone know why this might happen?

Answer (score 0):

Not having compiled the code with -g option may explain this. (locally VSCode take care of this but you have to configure your build process with the java debug flag or equivalent configuration).